Modern composition for flute and dancing
Hope the question fits here. I'm trying to remember without success of a composition for transverse flute in which the performer also has to dance and make some vocals. If I remember correctly, the song is called something like "A walk over the moon roulette". I think it was composed by an american, probably 10 or 15 years back.
I hope someone can help me in recalling this strange song.

Seems like an identification question to me, unfortunately these are off-topic here.

Ok, I got it now. The song is "Pirouette on a moon sliver" by Amy Beth Kirsten. One can watch a performance here.
